# Minecraft Forge - Cannot refer to an instance field while explicitly invoking a constructor

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

for my Minecraft mod I've written a custom button class so that when the button is pressed, it sends a packet to the server, to update a capability. The button is also supposed to change texture, so that the button with the same id as the "style" set in the capability, is red, while the others are grey.

However, one of the problems I've come across is that the the next button *after* the button with the correct id, is the button that is actually turned red (e.g if button with id 0 is the active id, button with id 1 is the button thats turned red instead).

Here's my button class:

```
package lk1905.gielinorcraft.client.gui.widget;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.Gielinorcraft;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.capability.attackstyle.AttackStyleCapability;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.capability.attackstyle.IAttackStyle;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.network.AttackStyleClientPacket;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.network.PacketHandler;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.ImageButton;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class AttackStyleButton extends ImageButton{

    
    private PlayerEntity player =  Minecraft.getInstance().player;
    private IAttackStyle styleCap = player.getCapability(AttackStyleCapability.STYLE_CAP).orElse(null);
    private static int yTex = 0;
    
    public AttackStyleButton(int xIn, int yIn, int widthIn, int heightIn, int xTexStartIn, int yTexStartIn,
            int yDiffTextIn, ResourceLocation resourceLocationIn, IPressable onPressIn) {
        super(xIn, yIn, widthIn, heightIn, xTexStartIn, yTexStartIn, yDiffTextIn, resourceLocationIn, onPressIn);
    }
    
    public AttackStyleButton(int xIn, int yIn, int slotId) {    
        this(xIn, yIn, 56, 20, 137, yTex, 0 , new ResourceLocation(Gielinorcraft.MODID, "textures/gui/combat.png"), (button) -> {
            PacketHandler.sendToServer(new AttackStyleClientPacket(slotId));
        });
    
        if(styleCap.getActiveStyleId() == slotId) {
            yTex = 23;
        }else {
            yTex = 0;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Before here, i Went to the Minecraft forge website to ask what the problem is, and they claimed that the variable "yTex" shouldn't be static (They won't actually say why though, just "please learn what static means", even though I can't find similar enough examples for me to understand why).

The problem with that though, is the reason I made it static in the first place is because eclipse gives me the error "Cannot refer to an instance field yTex while explicitly invoking a constructor", located in the second constructor, and told me to make it static.

From what I understand, the error is because as yTex is instanced, it doesn't have a value before the constructor is called, so the constructor can't continue. But I'm not sure how to rewrite the class so that it does the same thing. I want the value of yTex to be set within this class, with the if statement deciding its value.

So how would I rewrite this class so that it does what I'm already telling it to do, but with yTex as not static?

Comment: This is so close to a good question because it includes what the OP has researched (a surprisingly rare sight).  LK1905, if you could switch out your Minecraft code to a more generic [mre], then this question would be something that future users could benefit from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add logic to compute a value to be passed into a superclass's constructor, you can't use any instance variables or methods from the calling class because nothing about the calling class exists at the time that the superclass's constructor is called.

A static method can be used to run code to compute the value to be passed as a parameter to a superclass's constructor.  The same rule mentioned above applies to the code in this static method.  Here's how you'd use this technique to compute the value to be passed into your superclass's constructor in place of the computed `yTex` value:

```
package lk1905.gielinorcraft.client.gui.widget;

import lk1905.gielinorcraft.Gielinorcraft;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.capability.attackstyle.AttackStyleCapability;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.capability.attackstyle.IAttackStyle;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.network.AttackStyleClientPacket;
import lk1905.gielinorcraft.network.PacketHandler;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.ImageButton;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class AttackStyleButton extends ImageButton{

    private static int yTex(int slotId) {
        PlayerEntity player =  Minecraft.getInstance().player;
        IAttackStyle styleCap = player.getCapability(AttackStyleCapability.STYLE_CAP).orElse(null);
        if (styleCap.getActiveStyleId() == slotId) {
            return 23;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    public AttackStyleButton(int xIn, int yIn, int slotId) {    
        super(xIn, yIn, 56, 20, 137, yTex(slotId), 0 , new ResourceLocation(Gielinorcraft.MODID, "textures/gui/combat.png"), (button) -> {
            PacketHandler.sendToServer(new AttackStyleClientPacket(slotId));
        });    
    }
}
```

You said in a comment **"The first constructor is there only because this class is extended from another class. The second constructor is the one I use."**  I'm not sure what you're saying here about why you have the first constructor.  If the `AttackStyleButton` class is only ever instantiated using the second constructor, then there's no reason for the first constructor to exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first example, did I also need to make `yTex = yTexStartIn` in the first constructor? Because `yTex` isn't even being used, so it just uses the value set in the second constructor, which is 0.

Comment: And the second example also didn't do anything. Making `yTex = yTextInitialValue` only sets the inital value of `yTex` to the value of `yTexInitialValue`. Changing the value of `yTex` doesn't change the value of `yTexInitialValue`, so that remains 0, so using that in the constructor keeps the value at 0, `yTex` isn't being used at all.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your problem the first time, but maybe I do now.  In the second constructor, you want to pass either 0 or 23 to the superclass's constructor based on if `styleCap.getActiveStyleId() == slotId`?.  I can show you how to do this.  I still don't know what you want for the first constructor though.  You only talk about `yTex`, but you don't use that in the first constructor, so I don't know what you want to do there.

Comment: The first constructor is there only because this class is extended from another class. The second constructor is the one I use.

Comment: I thought I needed the first constructor, but I just needed to make the `this` in the second constructor `super` instead. But your answer works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Doh!  I totally missed that!  I didn't notice the `this` vs `super`.  Sorry about that! - Fixed now.